# Escaping colon character in Android selinux

Tags: android, linux, android-source, selinux

I'm trying to create a custom selinux policy for my AOSP build wherein untrusted apps can write to `/sys/class/leds/led:flash_torch/brightness` thereby controlling the flashlight.

To do this, I edited the following files in `external/sepolicy`

### **domain.te**

```
allow domain sys_flashlight:file rw_file_perms;
```

### **file.te**

```
type sys_flashlight, fs_type;
```

### **untrusted_app.te**

```
allow untrusted_app sys_flashlight:file rw_file_perms;
```

Now, the final piece of the puzzle is the file `genfs_contexts`.
Ideally, I would want to change this file to contain something like:

```
genfscon proc /sys/class/leds/led:flash_torch/brightness u:object_r:sys_flashlight:s0
```

First, bear in mind that **the above statement is wrong**. `genfscon proc` is meant to only be used with `procfs`. Ignoring that, Since the file path contains the `:` character, the build process complains by stating:

```
external/sepolicy/genfs_contexts:11:ERROR 'syntax error' at token ':' on line 12972:
genfscon proc /sys/class/leds/led:flash_torch/brightness u:object_r:sysfs_flashlight:s0
genfscon proc /foreground u:object_r:proc_foreground:s0
checkpolicy:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
make: *** [out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

How can I escape the `:` character while writing the selinux policies?

**edit**: I've already tried quoting the path and using `\` to try and escape the `:` with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the parser statements for checkpolicy:

```
policy_parse.y:139:%token GENFSCON
policy_parse.y:750:genfs_context_def    : GENFSCON filesystem path '-' identifier security_context_def
policy_parse.y:752:         | GENFSCON filesystem path '-' '-' {insert_id("-", 0);} security_context_def
policy_parse.y:754:                        | GENFSCON filesystem path
```

We see GENFSCON's path token is what is expanding, which is defined as:

```
policy_scan.l:252:"/"({alnum}|[_\.\-/])*            { return(PATH); }
```

Thus : is not valid in the set.

This seems like a bug that the character set does not include these.